# Rabbitmq :: Message is never removed from stream queue

Tags: stream, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have created an [stream](https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html) queue in the rabbitmq of my project and configured max-age to 1 minute. I sent a message to the queue,all the consumers consumed the message, but the message is remaining in the queue (I waited more than 1 minute) as "ready". My worry is about accumulation of messages in the HD of rabbitmq instance.

So, my question is: All the messages marked as "ready" are stored in the HD, even after all consumer consumed the messages? If yes, how can I could purge (in this case, max-age is not working for it) these messages from HD of rabbitmq instance?

[image: print 1]

[image: print 2]

Comment: same problem here, did you found a solution?

Comment: @MichelAndrade, I published the answer

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I found:

- It's not possible to avoid to store data into HD or make a purge, but it's possible to prevent excessive disk usage.
- Add the argument x-stream-max-segment-size-bytes to the queue decreasing the default size to a size that is OK for your necessity. I defined 1 mb, for example. More details: https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html#declaring
- At least one segment file will always remain, so if you just send 1 message and wait, it will remain on disk forever. However, if you keep publishing, a new segment file gets created at some point and the retention process kicks in. Files that only contain messages older than the retention period will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

That is the design; see https://www.rabbitmq.com/streams.html#retention

> Streams are implemented as an immutable append-only disk log. This means that the log will grow indefinitely until the disk runs out. To avoid this undesirable scenario it is possible to set a retention configuration per stream which will discard the oldest data in the log based on total log data size and/or age.

> There are two parameters that control the retention of a stream. These can be combined. These are either set at declaration time using a queue argument or as a policy which can be dynamically updated. ...

```
max-age:

valid units: Y, M, D, h, m, s

e.g. 7D for a week

max-length-bytes:

the max total size in bytes
```

> NB: retention is evaluated on per segment basis so there is one more parameter that comes into effect and that is the segment size of the stream. The stream will always leave at least one segment in place as long as the segment contains at least one message. When using broker-provided offset-tracking, offsets for each consumer are persisted in the stream itself as non-message data.

But I see what you mean.

I suggest you ask on the rabbitmq-users Google group where the RabbitMQ engineers hang out; they don't monitor SO closely.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, the messages is nerver deleted.

[image]